# Spring MVC mapping @RequestBody with variables containing a dot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am doing a POST request to my Rest Contoller with the following object:

```
{
  "relationship.name": "someting"
}
```

I'd like to map that to a POJO:

```
public class Request {
  private String relationshipName;

  // Getters, setter and contructor
}
```

How would I dot that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annotate your property with `@JsonProperty`

```
public class Request {

    @JsonProperty("relationship.name")
    private String relationshipName;

    ...
}
```

By default, the mapping will use the variable name as the key for the property. So without the annotation, it would expect `relationshipName`. `@JsonProperty` allows you to customize the key without changing the variable name.

Comment: Isn't there a 'global' configuration method to specify a rule that applies to te whole application?

Comment: There is a global configuration, but the available settings do not include your use case. In your `application.properties`, you can specify `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy`. The possible naming strategies can be found here: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html

Comment: Thx for the infot though

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried using `@JsonProperty` on `relationshipName`?

@JsonProperty(name), tells Jackson ObjectMapper to map the JSON property name to the annotated Java field's name.